# C++ runtime API

Tags: c++, api, runtime

I want to create an application that, when executed, has runtime functions that are accessible by other applications.

For example, a C++ application that stores values in files and retrieves this information. While this application is running, any other C++ applications could access it's save and retrieve functionality to save and retrieve data, but it should have no other connection to this system.

Comment: AFAIK this is not part of the C++ language, but rather the "environment" (operating system/platform) your application will be running on. So specify your platform.

Comment: Read about [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). For more function-call interface you might want to read about [remote-procedure calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). None of it is part of standard C++, it's all system dependent.

Comment: System is Linux (Ubuntu, 14.01). Would this make more sense over a network connection? Should the application provide a network API, even thought it shouldn't have outside connections?

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html - a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple job for web services, or a remote database, or even an LDAP server.

Store and retrieve are operations common to all of these.

If the goal is to learn some specific technology, then ask a more specific question. Otherwise, don't reinvent any wheels. There are plenty of things out there for store and retrieve.

One of the simplest "store and retrieve" APIs I know of is Berkeley DB or Sleepycat.

We built a giant, clustered, simple key based database for a major telecom company using LDAP on top of Berkeley DB (aka Sleepycat). All open-source software and commodity hardware and it supports mission critical operations for millions of customers.

A more modern rendition of this might use memcached as well.

If you go HTTP based, you can use something simple as libcurl against an Apache web server to implement "RESTful" services with GET and PUT commands.

If you run it locally (same server), and access via localhost (127.0.0.1) then there is very little latency in the TCP stack, and it amounts to little more than memcpys at the kernel level.

Comment: That was just an example, and I dont want to reinvent any wheels. A more specific example would be, this application should have a check function, if an event occurs, and a retrieve event function, so that any other application that wants to check if event happened on the base application, it can retrieve the event data.

Answer (score 0):

simple message passing would do, say, [JSON](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson) over [ØMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall), or i.e. all in all, [msgpack-rpc](https://github.com/msgpack-rpc/msgpack-rpc-cpp) or [protobuf-remote](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-remote/wiki/GettingStartedCpp) or [Cap'n Proto RPC](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/rpc.html)

Comment: Those last two seem to be what I want. They also kinda look hard to use.

Comment: msgpack should be the easiest to start, since it doesn't need a code generator. I'd say, it's easier than any fragile low-level interprocess or pipe solution. The code is declarative and you basically only write what you need.